# PHP - Visitors Online Counter

Tags: php, session, counter

I have the following code to count visitors on my PHP site. It works fine on my local development machine using WampServer but when I uploaded my files to my hosting account for testing I realized that it does not work properly.

I get really high number count and also noticed the session are never deleted so they just keep accumulating.

It is a simple session counter. Is there a better way of doing it? Could some one please show me or point me to some article? **Thank you!**

```
<?php
//------------------------------------------------------------
// VISITORS ONLINE COUNTER
//------------------------------------------------------------
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
function visitorsOnline()
{
    $session_path = session_save_path();
    $visitors = 0;
    $handle = opendir($session_path);

    while(( $file = readdir($handle) ) != false)
    {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            if(preg_match('/^sess/', $file))
            {
                $visitors++;
            }
        }
    }

    return $visitors;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your own internal counting system then I would suggest, storing such information related to website in database. And update the record everytime a user browses the website.

Answer (score 4):

If this is shared hosting, you're counting *everyone's* session files, not just your own. That's why the number is huge and largely unrelated to how many people are on *your* site.

Answer (score 3):

The best (free) way to count visitors is here: http://www.google.com/analytics.

If you want more realtime data, (for instance, currently active users) try: http://www.woopra.com/

If you're set on maintaining who is active on your site with your own code, I'd do so with a "last action" date field in your database on the users table.  You will be able to do a PHP equivalent query to `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Users WHERE #{Time.now} > #{15.minutes.ago}`

If you want to track anonymous users as well, rather than using the Users table, make a table with the visitor's IP as the identifying field and use the same technique mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem on the production server is that sessions are simply never deleted, you have two options:

- Lower the session expiry time on your PHP installation.
- Examine the last-modified date of the session files and only count them towards your total if they were modified within a certain amount of time from now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure that reading the session files in the session dir is the best method.

Why not have a write on a db table for every page load. Then have a read that counts the number of unique users in the last x minutes?

It sounds db intensive but unless your site is ultra-busy, I can't see a problem.